# Why index.html is rendered in Node.js

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a handler for '/', which redirects to `/login.html`. 
However, even though i'm explicitly calling to redirection, the page that is rendered is STILL index.html.

it's pretty lame behaviour, since I'm expecting A and gets B.
How can I solve it?

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

MW:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login.html');
    }
});

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/index.html',
      failureRedirect: '/login.html'
  })
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not authenticated? The only redirect I see happens *only if* there is no authenticated user. Try it in an incognito browser session & see what happens.

Comment: yes. i'm also deleting the cookies every time.

Comment: The next step would be to add a `console.log` in your middleware just to see if `req.user` is, in fact, `undefined`. It could be an empty object or some other value that you need to test for.

Comment: I did it before posting the question. the user is undefined, and the redirect gets called. and instead of login.html, I get index.html. strange!